# Apply step gradient color in echart [gauge-ring]

Tags: javascript, echarts, apache-echarts

[gauge-ring](https://echarts.apache.org/examples/en/editor.html?c=gauge-ring)

What should I write in the color attribute? to make the color similar to the image below

[image]

```
progress: {
  itemStyle: {
    color: ????
  }
},
```

I tried the following code before, but it seems to have no effect

```
progress: {
  itemStyle: {
    color: [
      [0.25, '#FF6E76'],
      [0.5, '#FDDD60'],
      [0.75, '#58D9F9'],
      [1, '#7CFFB2']
    ]
  }
},
```

Comment: did you find any solution ?